Sign Tool for Azure Trusted Service Account Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147467259/0x80004005)
I'm getting this error when trying to use SignTool to sign my msix file.
I've verified I have Trusted Signing Certificate Profile Signer role assigned in Azure.
I also verified the publisher name of the AppxManifest.xml in the msix matches my certificate profile.
CN=Publisher Name, O=Organization Name, L=City, S=Province, C=CA
Following this procedure
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/trusted-signing/how-to-signing-integrations
& "C:\temp\test\microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools.10.0.22621.3233.nupkg\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /v /debug /fd SHA256 /tr "http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com" /td SHA256 /dlib "C:\temp\test\microsoft.trusted.signing.client.1.0.53.nupkg\bin\x64\Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.dll" /dmdf "C:\temp\test\metadata.json" "C:\temp\test\my-app_1.0.128.0_x64.msix"
Trusted Signing
Version: 1.0.53
"Metadata": {
"Endpoint": "https://wus2.codesigning.azure.net",
"CodeSigningAccountName": "",
"CertificateProfileName": "",
"CorrelationId": "",
"ExcludeCredentials": []
}
Submitting digest for signing...
Unhandled managed exception
Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)
Headers:
Date: Fri, 10 May 2024 21:09:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
x-azure-ref: REDACTED
X-Cache: REDACTED
Content-Length: 0
at Azure.CodeSigning.CertificateProfileRestClient.SignAsync(String codeSigningAccountName, String certificateProfileName, SignRequest body, String xCorrelationId, String clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.CodeSigning.CertificateProfileClient.StartSignAsync(String codeSigningAccountName, String certificateProfileName, SignRequest body, String xCorrelationId, String clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.Core.DigestSigner.SignAsync(UInt32 algorithm, Byte[] digest, SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.Core.DigestSigner.Sign(UInt32 algorithm, Byte[] digest, SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle)
at AuthenticodeDigestSignExWithFileHandleManaged(_CRYPTOAPI_BLOB* pMetadataBlob, UInt32 digestAlgId, Byte* pbToBeSignedDigest, UInt32 cbToBeSignedDigest, Void* hFile, _CRYPTOAPI_BLOB* pSignedDigest, _CERT_CONTEXT** ppSignerCert, Void* hCertChainStore)
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147467259/0x80004005)

The issue was my authentication "InteractiveBrowserCredential" was not working for some reason. I had to disable all authentication options except Azure CLI and retry. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli.
{
  "Endpoint": "https://eus.codesigning.azure.net",
  "CodeSigningAccountName": "account",
  "CertificateProfileName": "profile",
  "ExcludeCredentials": [
    "ManagedIdentityCredential",
    "EnvironmentCredential",
    "WorkloadIdentityCredential",
    "SharedTokenCacheCredential",
    "VisualStudioCredential",
    "VisualStudioCodeCredential",
    
    "AzurePowerShellCredential",
    "AzureDeveloperCliCredential",
    "InteractiveBrowserCredential"
  ]
}


Thank you!! This saved me. I'm baffled as to why this didn't appear in any Microsoft documentation.

For 403s there can be a few things that can cause this, please check/verify the below:

Check Trusted Signing role.
Check Trusted Signing account name and Trusted Signing Certificate profile name n your metadata.json.
Check dlib and dlib path
Install C++ Redistributables: Download link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
Check .Net version, dlib version and Windows SDK
Check if Trusted Signing role is assigned to the identity trying to sign the file.
Check if the corresponding Identity Validation is in "Completed" state.
Verify if you access to the Trusted Signing endpoint from the VM or machine you are trying to sign from?Try executing the action on a different VM or machine. It can be a potential network issue.


Trusted Signing role -> went to IAM under the Trusted Signing Account and verified I have Trusted Signing Certificate Profile Signer role
Trusted Signing account name -> taken from the Trusted Signing Account web page in Azure
